# String comparison in batch file never matching

Tags: windows, batch-file

I  have the following snippet

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET copyableTomcat="C:\test\source"
SET tomcatNode[2]="C:\test\source"

set x=2

IF %copyableTomcat% == %%tomcatNode[%x%]%% (
    call echo "ignoring " %%tomcatNode[%x%]%%
) ELSE (
    call echo "done"
)
```

However, the if statment is NEVER matching, and always goes into the else statement.

I am unsure if i am mistypying something or missing something completely

Comment: You may read full details on this management at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%%var%%` only works with `call`.

- Use `!` to expand the value since you're already using delayed expansion
- No need for quotes in `echo`
- No need to use `call` with delayed expansion in this case

---

```
IF %copyableTomcat%==!tomcatNode[%x%]! (
    echo ignoring !tomcatNode[%x%]!
) ELSE (
    echo done
)
```